Bound on q in Diophantine approximation
Been going over roths theorem and and a common comment is that its not an effective method. I presume the reason why we care about this is that it would allow us to find a bound on the size of q required?
But liouvilles theorem is effective, you can compute a bound $c = (n^2(1+|\alpha|)^{n-1}H)^{-1}$ where $H = max\{|a_0|,\dots, |a_n|\}$ is the maximum of the absolute value of the coefficients of f.
That is we know that
\begin{equation*}
\left| \alpha-\frac{p}{q} \right|>\frac{C}{q^{n+\varepsilon}}
\end{equation*}
for all $\varepsilon >0$ and all rationals where $q>0$.
I dont immediately see how this gives us a bound on the size of $q$ that doesn't also depend on $p$?
